# Get output from BAT file using Java

Tags: java, networking, windows-7, process, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run a .bat file and get the output. I can run it but I can't get the results in Java:

```
String cmd = "cmd /c start C:\\workspace\\temp.bat";

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = r.exec(cmd);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() ));

String s ;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The result is `null`. No idea why I get this. Note that I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using "cmd /c start [...]" to run a batch file will create a sub process instead of running your batch file directly.

Thus, you won't have access to its output.
To make it work, you should use:

```
String cmd = "C:\\workspace\\temp.bat";
```

It works under Windows XP.

Comment: this solved it
i have another problem which 
the bat file contains 
start run.bat command
and i need the other result too 
:(

Comment: You can use **CALL** to run an other batch files inside your primary script. See [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) and [link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true) for references.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start a new thread that would read terminal output stream and copy it to the console, after you call `process.waitFor()`.

Do something like:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

Better approach will be to use the `ProcessBuilder` class, and try writing something like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
builder.redirectInput();
Process process = builder.start();

while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
    System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
}
```

Comment: dude i tried this didn't work 
I'm getting null value instead of command result

Comment: in the  ProcessBuilder 
there is no  .redirectInput(); method
any suggestion? 
i use NetBeans BTW

Answer (score -1):

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader( pr.getErrorStream() ));
```

instead use

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream ));
```

Comment: Don't ignore the error stream.  For robust code, both must be consumed.

Comment: for both while loop required separately

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.