# Stopping Minecraft Server in Eclipse

Tags: java, batch-file, minecraft, bukkit

I have been trying this for hours and I don't know what to do. I'm creating a Minecraft Bukkit plugin which it's supposed to have a "restart" command, which sends some warning messages and after that I would like to close the server. I created a batch file to do it but, I want Java to do it for me when the warnings are over, something like, idk:

open("C:/Users/Blablabla/Desktop/close.bat");

And for the moment I have this:

```
public String document = "C:/Users/Joan-Server/Desktop/Server/closer.bat";

if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("restart")) {
    while(x != 0) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(plugin.name + ChatColor.GOLD + "¡ATENCIÓN! " + ChatColor.WHITE + "Reinicio del servidor en "
            + ChatColor.RED + x + " segundos.");
        //Try--
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        x = x - 1;
    }
    //Try--
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. If i understand correctly, you are trying to run a batch file from a Java program ?

Comment: Where is the [tag:batch-file]?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to execute your bat file:

```
try{    
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/path/to/file.bat");
    p.waitFor();

}catch( IOException ex ){
    //Catch if file doesn't exist or is inaccessible 
}
catch( InterruptedException ex ){
    //If the p.waitFor() is interrupted     
}
```

Use this to execute your restart script and you should be good to go! Assuming your restart script stops the server, waits, and starts the server again.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've been trying that option before but idk why I always got an error. Now is working perfectly!

Comment: Perfect, would you mind accepting this as the answer? Thanks :)

Comment: @JoanGómezHaro please accept the answer. This will reward CuriousOne for the good answer and it will let other users know the questions has already been answered. You can do this by clicking on the check mark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do your restart directly from your plugin via

```
getServer().dispatchCommand(getServer().getConsoleSender(), "restart");
```

If you really want to run the batch file, use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Blablabla\\Desktop\\close.bat");
```

If you also want to handle the console output of the bat file, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061268/get-output-from-bat-file-using-java).